# How to update firebase query?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my app i'm sending this query:

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
var time: String?

if defaults.valueForKey("chatsLoadedTime") != nil {
    time = "\(defaults.valueForKey("chatsLoadedTime") as! NSDate)"
}
chatsRef.queryOrderedByChild("updatedTime").queryStartingAtValue(time).observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snap in
```

Inside this query i update variable `time` and i want to update this `chatsRef` query to start at new value `time`. How can i do this?

My structure is:

```
user
-userID
--chatRooms
---chatRoomID
----updatedTime
----recieverName
----lastMes
----read
----recieverID
```

I'm querying chatRooms, where updatedTime is bigger than passed time variable. When i receive snapshot from firebase i update variable time and want to query chats, where updatedTime is bigger than updated variable time.

Comment: Based on the question, you always want to be query'ing for the latest post by time. i.e. A query is observing the posts node. When a post is made at 8, you want to be notified of that so then the query can be updated to observe for posts after 9. Then when a post is made at 9, you want the query to observe posts after 10. Does that sound correct?

Comment: looks similar. But with a small correct. "When a post is made at 8, you want to be notified of that so then the query can be updated to observe for posts after 8(not 9, and so on)."

Comment: I updated my answer to better reflect your question. At this point though, it seems like you always want to be notified of the most recent (aka last) post. So if a post occurs at 8 you will be notified of that post, then another post happens at 8:01, you want to be notified of that post. Then a post occurs at 8:05 you want to be notified of that post. Am I on track?

Answer (score 2):

It appears what you are asking is

> How do I query for all of the chatsRef child nodes starting at a particular time and when that notification occurs, stop observing that time, increment the time and watch for that time.

It helps if we know your Firebase data structure and what your complete query looks like but it appears you going the right direction:

Assuming you have a structure

```
chatsRef
  chat_00
    updated_time: "03"
  chat_01
    updated_time: "07"
  chat_02
    updated_time: "02"
```

and your query

```
let chatsRef = self.myRootRef.childByAppendingPath("chatsRef")

chatsRef.queryOrderedByChild("updated_time").queryStartingAtValue("02").observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snap in

    for child in snap.children {
        if let time = child.value["updated_time"] as? String {
            print(time)
        } 
    }
})
```

this will return all child nodes starting at 02, so the output is

```
02
07
```

and any future additions or changes to the existing node where updated_time is 02 or greater will return the results.

So if a child was added to the chatsRef node that contained updated_time: "04" then these results would be returned automatically

```
02
04
07
```

Keep in mind that .Value returns all of the child nodes that match the query criteria so you need to iterate over them by .children to get each nodes value.

Comment: You misunderstood me :( 
I want to update queryStartingValue after every time when I receive values from firebase. I want to set it to current time. 

For example: current time is 20:00.
I send query:
`time = "18:00";
chatsRef.queryOrderedByChild("updated_time").queryStartingAtValue(time)`
When I receive results I update value `time = "20:00"`
But I will still receive results at 19:00 for example, because queryStartingValue wasn't updated.
Bur I want next query observe from 20:00, not 18:00

Comment: @TarasNikulin It's not clear what you mean by 'when I receive values from firebase'. There's nothing in your code that you would be receiving values from other than the query. Which values are you referring to? Can you post your Firebase structure? There's just not enough information in the question to really answer it.