# Swift Firebase: Update specific objects resulting from Firebase query

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following structure in my Firebase DB:

[image: Firebase JSON]

I am looking to update the `read` attribute to `true` for all objects with a particular `mealID`. I have attempted this:

```
if let selectedIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                meals[(selectedIndexPath as NSIndexPath).row].unreadNotification=false
                let mealId = mealIds[(selectedIndexPath as NSIndexPath).row]
                let notificationsRef = ref.child("notifications")
                //get all notifications with this mealId
                var mealNotifications = notificationsRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "mealId").queryEqual(toValue: mealId)
                //notificationRef.updateChildValues(["read":true])
            }
```

The query is outputting the correct notification objects, I am just not sure of how to update these specific objects (using `mealNotifications`). Any ideas?

**EDIT**

I have added an observe event, however I am not receiving any objects in the output (I am expecting a single output). I believe this is because I am looking on the notification ID level, rather than the `mealID` level. How can I correct this in the query?

```
if let selectedIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                meals[(selectedIndexPath as NSIndexPath).row].unreadNotification=false
                let mealId = mealIds[(selectedIndexPath as NSIndexPath).row]
                let notificationsRef = ref.child("notifications")
                //get all notifications with this mealId
                var mealNotifications = notificationsRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "mealId").queryEqual(toValue: mealId).observe(.value, with: {snapshot in
                    print("MEALS:",snapshot)
                    })
                //notificationRef.updateChildValues(["read":true])
            }
```

Comment: You'll need to attach an observer, loop over the children and call `child.ref.updateChildValues()`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36821000/how-to-update-firebase-query

Comment: Thanks. It seems my query is incorrect, as I am trying to look a level below notificationsRef. Is there a way of specifying that the byChild argument should be a level down?

Comment: I've added the updated code above

Comment: The property you query in is always a level lower. Your query is correct. But you need to loop over the children in your block as I said before. When you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result.

Answer (score 0):

The below worked:

```
if let selectedIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                meals[(selectedIndexPath as NSIndexPath).row].unreadNotification=false
                let mealId = mealIds[(selectedIndexPath as NSIndexPath).row]
                let notificationsRef = ref.child("notifications")
                //get all notifications with this mealId
                var mealNotifications = notificationsRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "mealID").queryEqual(toValue: mealId).observe(.value, with: {snapshot in
                    let enumerator = snapshot.children
                    while let rest = enumerator.nextObject() as? FIRDataSnapshot {
                        notificationsRef.child(rest.key).child("read").setValue(true)
                        }
                        })
                    tableView.reloadRows(at: [selectedIndexPath], with: .none)
                }
```