# How to update a single value of key in every child from firebase?

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase-realtime-database

I am just stucked at this since last few hours and I have tried everything that is possible to update these values in firebase.

[image: Here is the value to be updated]

I want to update

> is_read_p: "0"

to

> is_read_p: "1"

for every record in the database.

So far, I have tried this code,

```
[[[[_mainRef child:@"messages"] child:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"359_361"]]childByAutoId] updateChildValues:@{@"is_read_c":@"0"}];
```

But, instead of updating, it adds three more child like this:

[image: Inserted instead of Updating]

I know there must be a silly mistake or I might be missing something. Please help me finding that missing part. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

- Each time you call `childByAutoId`, the client creates a reference to a new unique child node. Since you then call `updateChildValues` on that new location, you're creating a new child node, instead of updating an existing one.
- Firebase doesn't support update queries. You'll need to execute the query, process each matching node, and update them individually.

  Also see:

  - [Swift Firebase: Update specific objects resulting from Firebase query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39819474/swift-firebase-update-specific-objects-resulting-from-firebase-query)